# Font size varies for different iOS devices

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Can any one tell me how to handle font size for different iOS resolution devices?
I am working on cocos2dx and using CCLabelTTF.

What happens is that same font size appears differently iPhone and iPad-HD.
Font size is perfect for iPhone and is pretty small for iPad-HD. I know its because of different resolutions so What is the solution.

One easy solution is to detect device and set size accordingly but it will take 5-6 checks which i dont consider a valid solution. Can any one else have a good solution ?

Comment: The best way is to use Cocosbuilder

Comment: if you have a singleton entity (like GameManager), you could make a read-only property for type of current device there and run device check only once, when initializing this singleton